# Russian text normalization dataset

Tags: text, russia

I want to train a model for converting written expressions into spoken forms in Russian. I have come across the kaggle dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/c/text-normalization-challenge-russian-language,

but it has a lot of errors. (And they are not random noise; they are systematic errors, because the set was marked up by an algorithm, not by people.)

Are there any other datasets for Russian text normalization?

Comment: Do you mean a corpus? https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=russian+corpus&ref=searchresults

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this link will be useful: https://github.com/Koziev/NLP_Datasets

Comment: Please expand this answer with some details